# Dockerfile ARG always null

Tags: docker

I have spent quite a lot of time to get to the bottom of this. What I am trying to achieve is to pass a connection string to dockerfile as a build argument from docker-compose. The below is a very simple snippet which repoduces the problem. The output of `Write-Host ${SOMEARG}` is always null.

Having the below dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/iis
ARG SOMEARG=test

SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]

RUN Write-Host 'HERE:';`
    Write-Host ${SOMEARG}
```

I have output:

```
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/iis
 ---> 85fb57957cf1
Step 2/4 : ARG SOMEARG=test
 ---> Running in 84a7fc37994c
Removing intermediate container 84a7fc37994c
 ---> 2099e56f466f
Step 3/4 : SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]
 ---> Running in 61852677a26a
Removing intermediate container 61852677a26a
 ---> b934f778c13b
Step 4/4 : RUN Write-Host 'HERE:';    Write-Host ${SOMEARG}
 ---> Running in 3fde911ecdc1
HERE:

Removing intermediate container 3fde911ecdc1
 ---> 5331ce22c3ec
Successfully built 5331ce22c3ec
```

Comment: Does `ENV SOMEARG=${SOMEARG}` placed after your `ARG` line improve things?

Comment: @BMitch unfortunately does not. I am uncertain if I actually understand the concept.

Comment: Can you try just `RUN echo ${SOMEARG}`

Comment: @yamek tried both.

Answer (score 6):

Using `ARG` value of `ArgName` with default `SHELL` set to *PowerShell* can be done by referring to `$env:ArgName`.

Just remember to [understand how ARG and FROM interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact):

> An `ARG` declared before a `FROM` is *outside of a build stage*, so it **can’t** be used in any instruction after a `FROM`. To use the default value of an `ARG` declared before the first `FROM` use an `ARG` instruction without a value inside of a build stage.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is solved [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/542).

Since you are using a windows container, build args should be referenced using `%%`since cmd is the default shell.

```
FROM microsoft/iis
ARG SOMEARG=test

SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]

RUN Write-Host 'HERE:';`
    Write-Host %SOMEARG%
```

Comment: It works when I remove the #SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]. However, this is not solving my problem as I need to run many powershell commands and cmdlets.

Comment: Found out that this command is working RUN powershell -Command Write-Host %SOMEARG%

Comment: Powershell doesn't work with `%variable%` but rather with `$variable`.